# How to treat two different parameter with same file name in htaccess?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is what I mean using the example I have two types of links like-

```
http://example.com/type.php?category=movies
http://example.com/type.php?tags=movies
```

And I have used some code like this in htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^type/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) type.php?category=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^type/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) type.php?tags=$1 [NC,L]
```

But still no luck, the first one code that is on the first line of other like in this case the **?category** only works and the **?tags** don't work what could be the possible correct answer to tackle both?

Comment: You need to come up with something unique about each route, right now your second route is a duplicate of the first and will never fire. You can do something like `/type/category/movies`

Comment: why would you want to mix things up in the first place? Can't you keep it simple and clean? :/

Comment: To put it another way, from your directives (proposed URL structure) what would _you_ want to happen when a request comes in for `/type/movies`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the L from [NC,L] because it means that if .htaccess can apply this rule, you tell it to stop the rewriting here and so it won't execute the second line.

Here's more about the flags : [https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/rewrite/flags.html\](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/rewrite/flags.html%5C)

*" The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set. In most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules will be processed. "*

=-=

Also, as Chris Haas commented, if you're not enough specific about your rules and that the original URL from first rule is found in all other rules, then it will always only process first rule.
A good example to this is :

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_]+)/([a-z0-9_]+)/([a-z0-9_]+)$ index.php?param1=$1\
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_]+)/([a-z0-9_]+)/([a-z0-9_]+)$ index.php?param1=$1&param2=$2\
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_]+)/([a-z0-9_]+)/([a-z0-9_]+)$ index.php?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3\
```

As the first rule can be found in other rules (here both 2nd and 3rd, then these 2nd and 3rd will be considered as "same" as the first one and therefore not executed.

Comment: "Try to remove `L`" - No! You do only want one rule to be applied for something like this. It does not make sense to remove the `L` flag here. However, removing the `L` flag will have no effect anyway, because the output of the rule that matched is used as the input for the next - so it won't match anyway (and you don't want it to match). "A good example to this is" - An arguably _better_ example is already given in the question!

Comment: I'm just seeing now that indeed the rules are meant to have either category or tags as first parameter. If category is found then don't read other rules. If not test if first parameter is tags etc etc. Indeed. I dont know how I didn't get it. I may have misunderstood the problem.